# how to intrepret slightly complex pointer declarations

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am having a bit of trouble interpreting some pointer declarations. Hopefully someone can help me. This is for c99 syntax.
if I have something like

```
    typedef struct stuff thing;
    struct stuff{
        int a;
        char *(*b)[][2];
        int c;
        thing *(*d)[];
    }
```

although it may be redundant, how would you interpret b and d as? Also, is char *(*b)[][2] the same as **b[][2]? why or why not?

Thanks

Comment: Check out cdecl.org - for instance, here's [`b`](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=+char+*%28*b%29%5B%5D%5B2%5D%3B).

Comment: I also like this article about the "Right-Left Rule" http://ieng9.ucsd.edu/~cs30x/rt_lt.rule.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C declarations are always read from the inside out. Apart from that, you need to know the operator precedence: the array index operator has higher precedence than the dereferencing operator. This is why `d` is a pointer (`*d`) **to an array (`(*d)[]`) of pointers (`*(*d)[]`)** to `thing` (`thing *(*d)[];`) and not a pointer **to a pointer to an  array** of `thing`s.

As you see, precedence is the reason why `*a[]` and `(*a)[]` are not the same: the first is an array of pointers, the second is a pointer to an array.

So, the most important link for you is the [operator precedence table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence) in wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

`char *(*b)[][2];` declares `b` as a *pointer to an array of arrays of two `char` pointers*.  To interpret such expression keep remember; Assign the priority to the pointer declaration considering precedence and associative according to following table:

[image]

You can see some examples from [here](http://c-pointer.blogspot.in/2009/11/how-to-read-complex-pointers-in-c.html).

> is `char *(*b)[][2]` the same as `char **b[][2]` ? why or why not?

No. `char **b[][2]` declare `b` as an *array of arrays of two pointer to pointer to `char`*. For reason, see the above table.

Answer (score 0):

read declaration inside to outside, according to associativity.

say

```
char *(*b)[][2];
```

means:
a variable named `b`.

but what it is? oh, it's a pointer because of `*b`.

so then? associate with square bracket first, so `(*b)[][2]` means it's a pointer pointing to a 2-D array with length of 2 in 1st dimension.

but what's the type of array? `char *` indicates that.

so the whole declaration means, b is a pointer, pointing to a 2D `char *` array with length 2 in 1st dimension.

if it's

```
char **b[][2];
```

how things change then?

`b` goes with `[][2]` first, so it's `b[][2]` indicates `b` is a variable representing a 2D array, with length 2 in 1st dimension.

then adds `char **`, means that `b` is a 2D `char **` array with length 2 in 1st dimension.

by using typing system in C wisely, you can have a lot of amazing results. try to know more about type trees.

by making things clear, i think the interpretation of the second one is much simpler.

Comment: @mafso i think it should be 1st dimension? ... 3rd 2nd 1st. from right to left.

Comment: I didn't realize that it's not clear from where to count dimensions. I don't know, if any convention on this exists, it felt normal to me to count from the "outermost dimension" to the "innermost". Thinking about it, your way of counting is probably better.

Answer (score 0):

The interactive site [C gibberish ↔ English](http://cdecl.org) is very useful.

---

```
char *(*b)[][2]; // declare b as pointer to array of array 2 of pointer to char
```

`(*b)` is a pointer to TBD

`(*b)[][2]` is a pointer to array of array 2 of TBD

`char *(*b)[][2]` is a pointer to array of array 2 of pointer to char

---

```
char **b[][2]; // declare b as array of array 2 of pointer to pointer to char
```

`b` is a TBD

`b[][2]` is an array of array 2 of TBD

`char **b[][2]` is an array of array 2 of pointer to pointer to char

---

Not the same.  Notice how the `()` affect the order of interpretation.

For field `d`:

```
thing *(*d)[]; //    declare d as pointer to array of pointer to thing
               // or declare d as pointer to array of pointer to struct stuff
```